# How to include one jre based on os in nsis

Tags: nsis, java

I have two jre file in my source code.I have created two exe files based on user inputs and changed the outfile named.

Now based on outfile I want to include jre file.if outfile contains 64 then include 64 bit jre else 32 bit jre.
I have tried below code.but its not working?

```
    !ifdef PLATFORM64
    OutFile setup64.exe
    !else
    OutFile setup32.exe
    !endif 
Function .Oninit
 ${StrContains} $0 "64"  OutFile
 File /oname=$JRE_INSTALLER_FILE_NAME "$TEMP\jre-6u29-windows-x64.exe"
FunctionEnd
```

Questions:
1.How to  include any one jre file based on outfile named?

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
!ifdef PLATFORM64
OutFile setup64.exe
!else
OutFile setup32.exe
!endif

Function .Oninit
  var JRE_PLATFORM_FILE
  ${StrContains} $0 "64" $OutFile
    StrCmp $0 "" notfound
      StrCpy $JRE_PLATFORM_FILE "file-name-for-64-bit-JRE"
      Goto done
    notfound:
      StrCpy $JRE_PLATFORM_FILE "file-name-for-32-bit-JRE"
    done:
  File /oname=$JRE_INSTALLER_FILE_NAME $JRE_PLATFORM_FILE
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: But i cant use StrCpy command inside the OutFile.I got following error."Error: command StrCpy not valid outside Section or Function"

Comment: OK, I found the docs for StrContains, do hopefully my updated answer will work for you.